# What would be a good celebration of Physics SE's graduation anniversary?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, site-promotion

It's been almost a year since Physics Stack Exchange graduated from beta status - February 24, 2011, to be precise. Since we're coming up on our anniversary, it would be a great chance to do something special to

- celebrate nearly a year and a half of helping the internet with physics
- bring in more new posters to the site so our next year can be even better

The thing is, we (moderators) are short on ideas for what a fitting way to celebrate our anniversary would be, and besides the ideas should come from you, the community. Other sites often run [contests](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) around the time of their anniversaries, but we could do anything practical, and if we come up with a good idea, we can get some support (financial or otherwise) from Stack Exchange to make it happen. So with that in mind, **what are your ideas?**

If nobody posts feedback here, our anniversary may well pass without any recognition whatsoever...

Comment: My creativity does not come any further than the already mentioned contest idea unfortunately. The contest you refer to is quite straightforward, but maybe some quiz-like approach with a grand tour through physics is an alternative?

Comment: @Bernhard: not a bad idea, but it sounds like that could be a lot of work for whoever puts it together. That doesn't rule it out, it just means somebody's going to have to volunteer for it ;-)

Comment: It's great to see this post here. If anything becomes of the discussion, and you need anything from the Community Team, please let us know (community@stackexchange.com).

Comment: Since there was basically no feedback on this, we're not doing anything fancy - let's just be happy about a year's progress! (There has been some talk about top user swag, though.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Thanks for trying to put something together. Even though there wasn't enough interest to put together a celebration, I wanted to stop by and wish Physics a happy birthday and a great year ahead. :)

Comment: Maybe next year.

Answer (score 0):

Just to start throwing ideas out: I would kind of like to see a contest with prizes for the best *new users* especially. This could include recognition of:

- best question posted by a new user
- most upvotes accumulated on answer posted by a new user
- highest standing in the rep leagues for a new user

and so on. Of course this wouldn't exclude also doing something to recognize the people who have been contributing for a long time as well.

Answer (score 0):

An option might be having some kind of reward for people who go out and promote the site by posting links on other forums or social sites (Facebook, Google+, Twitter, Reddit, Digg, etc.). Perhaps just have a meta question to collect links, and give out a small reward to whoever posts one (and yes, I know this system is easily gamed, so maybe this isn't such a great idea).