# Can we have a candle on our logo?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

With our site's ["birthday" coming up](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/what-would-be-a-good-celebration-of-physics-ses-graduation-anniversary) in 3 days, I thought it would be kind of neat to put a candle on the site logo for the day, because the Mexican hat potential kind of looks like a cake if you don't think about it too hard. Can the SE design overlord (hi Jin) make this happen?

Comment: /me started thinking about it too hard. Confused now :P

Comment: @Jin (hope this works)

Comment: I guess the only way for Jin to get notified is @replying to a post of his, so [I did](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/new-site-design#comment2481_1018)

Comment: We haven't done site design tweaks for birthdays for other sites. But I think we definitely should do something! How about swag for top users? We normally do it close to site's bday.

Comment: @Jin Sure, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not do small design tweaks for things like this.  Google might be able to do daily fun doodles, but it would get out of hand we did that here given the number of sites we have (and we keep growing!)

Sorry!

For the birthday celebrations, we're looking for the communities to come together with the initiative to put something together.  It isn't really for the purpose of just sending swag just to send swag.  [**We do that for other things already**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1072/67)... (:

Comment: That's fair... this site seems to be noticeably lacking in initiative :-( I thought the candle might be something easy. (FWIW Aarthi told me to ask!)