# Physics swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 1340 reputation (as of Feb 24) and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Physics Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Physics Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: physics.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: physics.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: I have to ask: what's your business model? This offer seems to violate the "if it's free there's a catch" principle. Or would it invalidate your business model to explain what your business model is?

Comment: Thanks! That's cool!

Comment: @PeterMorgan I guess the business model is: get your "best" users to advertise your product. (and remember the old saying: only 20% of advertising covers its costs, but no one knows which 20%)

Comment: @PeterMorgan  Once, I got a mapmaker.google.com tshirt for a similar reason. On the back, it said 'Map your world\n mapmaker.google.com'. I've had countless people ask me what it meant, and I took great pleasure in explaining it. A few of them even joined mapmaker. Same concept here :D

Comment: @PeterMorgan: Admittedly the actual manner in which Stack Exchange expects this site to make them money is a mystery to me :-) However, I'm quite confident that there is no catch to this offer - you're not going to be subscribed to mailings, SE isn't going to sell your address to marketers, etc. AFAIK the only point of this offer is to drum up enthusiasm for the site among those who are demonstrably most likely to promote it, like EnergyNumbers said.

Comment: Got it, awesome!! Thanks! :D

Comment: Ok cool, but why did the people at math.SE get a mug also?

Comment: I've spend a couple of thousands of points on bounties. Does one get punished for that?

Comment: Why do I get **site not found** when I click on the link: http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens ?

Comment: This question should be closed because it will be unnecessarily bumped by [Community](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).