# Let's design and get some Physics Stack Exchange swag

Tags: discussion

e.g. shirts or hats.

It would be fun.
Post design proposals below as answers and we can take the top voted one after a couple weeks and place an order.

I'm happy to do the purchase and distribute the pieces to other users as appropriate, but if the mods can get the SE staff to do it for us that would be nice too.

Why?
Because they're going to take our Winter Bash hats and that's just not cool.

Comment: Are you thinking merit based swag (to represent contributions to the site) or something any member could buy?  Either way, I cant foresee any downside provided people like you (thank you) are willing to make it happen.

Comment: We (mods) are certainly willing to ask SE about this. They've printed things for us in the past, T-shirts and stickers, so they may be able to do it again. However, see also the [meta post about the now-defunct SE store](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137579/56541). On the other hand if we (community) do it ourselves, there may be licensing issues relating to the site name and logo. I imagine that SE would be okay with it but we probably shouldn't go printing our own stuff using trademarked designs without checking, at least.

Comment: @DavidZ yes indeed. Could you please ask the SE folks permission or see if they want to do it for us (for a cost of course, or not... whatever)?

Comment: @theNamesCross I think merit-based could be interesting, but that's not what I have in mind for this round. I'd like to simply get something representative of the site.

Comment: @DanielSank (2 comments up) Word is the SE people will have to discuss it and get back to us. Their next meeting is not until sometime after New Year's Day. Unofficially... we probably shouldn't expect any help with production (e.g. printing). As far as licensing or permission to use logos and such, there's not much to say, but [this comment](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1504#comment5297_1504) is encouraging.

Comment: @DavidZ thanks for the info. Looking forward to an update.

Comment: [Latecomer's regret](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/physics-swag-for-top-users)?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty huh?

Comment: @DanielSank Just kidding ;-). I kinda wish I'd been around for that initial handing out of P.SE swag, but oh well.

Comment: @DanielSank should we begin seeing who wants to place an order for the shirts?

Comment: @Kenshin I was hoping to have this come up in a chat session first.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Source:  [Physics swag for top users](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/physics-swag-for-top-users)

Comment: This can be a hat, not only as a 2D picture on a T-shirt!

Comment: Something on the back?

Comment: Note I also think a similar design could work with a black t-shirt.

Answer (score 11):

T-shirt design.

### Front:

[image]

### Back:

[image]

Notes: front image is of the equation for the standard model of particle physics; the back is a picture of a Mexican hat. The back picture could obviously be better, but I was in a tad bit of a hurry when I designed this. =) Designed on CustomInk, Gildan Ultra Cotton T-shirt, color: royal.

Comment: *Almost* good, but I cannot in good conscience upvote a design that uses Papyrus.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, I didn't know what font to use =) Okay, I'll get a different font.

Comment: What a Phys.SE shirt is that doesn't carry forward the crusade of anti-homework revolution; I wantz this; +1.

Comment: So in 2007-ish I was at plenary talk at an APS meeting when the speaker flashed a slide that looked a lot like the small print on the front of your design. I happened to be sitting in front a fairly prominent theorist, who leaned over to one of his graduate students and said "I hope you got all that; we'll discuss the details later." I approached this theorist afterwards, reminded him of the exchange, and admitted that I couldn't decide whether he'd been joking or serious. His response was, "Oh, God, yes. Of course I was joking. What a disaster for science communication that was."

Comment: Having said that: the design "What part of [unreadable mess of equations] don't you understand?" has appeared on t-shirts by other people and could conceivably be protected by copyright, if such things bother you. The homework quip is more unique to P.SE.

Comment: Heather, are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @JohnDuffield, the t-shirt design is sarcastic, but the proposal of the design is perfectly serious.

Comment: My reaction to a shirt like that is that I would only wear it if I understood the theory encapsulated in the expression in some detail and could at least point out what each term meant in some way. I can do that for Maxwell's Equations, but I can probably only pick out which group of terms goes with each fundamental interaction in that monster of a Lagrangian. Consequently I wouldn't buy one. Of course, your millage may vary, and notions of propriety differ, but you might want to know that some people think that way.

Comment: @dmckee, one thing I should point out (and I certainly understand your point of view) is that that picture could be substituted for some other set of equations that are perhaps not quite as monstrous.

Comment: Change the font, use Maxwell's equations, and get a better color/contrast for the Mexican hat... then it gets my vote (actually, it already got my vote - shhhhh).

Comment: @Floris, I agree, Maxwell's equations seem a better set for the front. I'll try to update it soon.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This is a black design inspired by: [Physics swag for top users](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/physics-swag-for-top-users)

Designed by CustomInk.com

Answer (score 4):

I will go with the simplest idea, a hat:

[image: hat design]

The shape of it might need some modification for it to be practical. But you get the idea.

[image]

Comment: If we could actually get hats made with the shape (or reasonably close to it) and color scheme of the SE logo, I'd be in for that!

Answer (score 3):

It's exciting that you all care about your site so much you want to wear your allegiance. The only concern I had when I heard about this was "what would our pesky lawyers say?". As a rule, ["It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317531/1438). That said, our VP of Community Growth [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244564/1438):

> We do not object to your individual use of the logo in a personal and private manner.
>
> Like, say for using the logo on a tee shirt you plan to wear yourself.

It gets a bit tricky when it comes to selling shirts. But as long as the charge is just to defray costs and it doesn't turn it into a business of some sort, I don't see any problem.

Unfortunately, we can't coordinate this event; y'all'll have to take care of that yourselves. You might have heard of our [#SOreadytohelp contest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303721/who-are-the-winners-in-the-soreadytohelp-t-shirt-drawing). It took [months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313937/10-million-questions-giveaway-what-happened) to distribute the prizes and we've concluded its just not one our strengths. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. We'll take enough funds from users to cover the cost of the shirts and shipping and no more. I'm happy to deal with the logistics :)

Comment: @DanielSank: Perfect.