# When did Physics StackExchange launch?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, history

[StackExchange launched in September 2009.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange)

When did Physics StackExchange launch in history?

Comment: Note that the September 2009 launch date for SE is a bit hazy. Stack Overflow [launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) on September 2008, with Server Fault and Super User coming after, and then a branching out into other areas. The 'launch date' of SE depends a fair bit on what you mean by that.

Answer (score 9):

One handy place for this information is [the user page of the Community ♦ user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), which gives the bot's inception date as 1 November 2010.

For more information, you can go to [the original Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics), which gives a detailed breakdown of the milestones:

- The original proposal was posted on 2 June 2010
- Private beta started on 2 November 2010
- Public beta started on 9 November 2010
- The site graduated from beta status on 24 February 2011 ([source](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/what-would-be-a-good-celebration-of-physics-ses-graduation-anniversary))

Answer (score 6):

The [list of Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites) shows some statistics about each site, including its age.  Physics launched six years ago, apparently in November of 2010.